# Running "rvm get stable" in my terminal doesn't do anything. How do I update RVM?

Tags: ruby, rvm

When I do "rvm get stable" nothing happens.

```
Last login: Sat Feb 11 18:22:14 on ttys000
Adams-MacBook-Pro:~ adam$ rvm -v

rvm 1.8.3 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]

Adams-MacBook-Pro:~ adam$ rvm get stable
```

notice nothing happened. It didn't update.

```
Adams-MacBook-Pro:~ adam$ rvm -v

rvm 1.8.3 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]

Adams-MacBook-Pro:~ adam$
```

How do I update my RVM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe `rvm get stable` is a newer command, that your version of rvm doesn't yet support.  Update yours using `rvm get latest` and the `get stable` option should become available to you for future updates.

You can test this by just typing in `rvm get` to see what your options are.

In the older version of rvm you also need to reload:

```
rvm get head
rvm reload
rvm get stable
```

Running the installer is also safe:

```
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
rvm reload
```